# how to scale the AKS Deployments using C#

Tags: c#, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have tried using the Patch Class to scale the Deployments but unable to do so. Please let me know how to do it. i have researched a lot but no proper docs on it/Example to achieve.

```
public static async Task<V1Scale> Scale([FromBody] ReplicaRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            // Use the config object to create a client.
            using (var client = new Kubernetes(config))
            {
                // Create a json patch for the replicas
                var jsonPatch = new JsonPatchDocument<V1Scale>();
            
                // Set the new number of repplcias
                jsonPatch.Replace(e => e.Spec.Replicas, request.Replicas);
                // Creat the patch

                var patch = new V1Patch(jsonPatch,V1Patch.PatchType.ApplyPatch);
                var list = client.ListNamespacedPod("default");
                
                //client.PatchNamespacedReplicaSetStatus(patch, request.Deployment, request.Namespace);
                //var _result = await client.PatchNamespacedDeploymentScaleAsync(patch, request.Deployment, request.Namespace,null, null,true,default);
               await client.PatchNamespacedDeploymentScaleAsync(patch, request.Deployment, request.Namespace,null, "M", true, default);
            
                
            }
        }
        catch (Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException e)
       {
         Console.WriteLine(e.Response.Content);
        
       }
        return null;
    }

    public class ReplicaRequest
    {
        public string Deployment { get; set; }
        public string Namespace { get; set; }
        public int Replicas { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to the community! What exact library do you use? Which version? Also which version of kubernetes cluster are you trying to apply replicas change?

Comment: I am using Kubernetes client library(KubernetesClient(5.0.13)) and I am applying changes on AKS Cluster with 1.19.9. Please let me what i am missing and after much i have reached here but unable to proceed further

Answer (score 1):

The `JsonPatchDocument<T>` you are using generates Json Patch, but you are specifying ApplyPatch.

Edit as of 2022-04-19:
The [kubernetes-client/csharp](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp) library changed the serializer to `System.Text.Json` and this doesn't support `JsonPatchDocument<T>` serialization, hence we have to do it beforehand

##### `From version 7 of the client library:`

```cs
var jsonPatch = new JsonPatchDocument<V1Scale>();
jsonPatch.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
{
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
};
jsonPatch.Replace(e => e.Spec.Replicas, request.Replicas);
var jsonPatchString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonPatch);
var patch = new V1Patch(jsonPatchString, V1Patch.PatchType.JsonPatch);
await client.PatchNamespacedDeploymentScaleAsync(patch, request.Deployment, request.Namespace);
```

##### `Works until version 6 of the client library:`

Either of these should work:

Json Patch:

```cs
var jsonPatch = new JsonPatchDocument<V1Scale>();
jsonPatch.Replace(e => e.Spec.Replicas, request.Replicas);
var patch = new V1Patch(jsonPatch, V1Patch.PatchType.JsonPatch);
await client.PatchNamespacedDeploymentScaleAsync(patch, request.Deployment, request.Namespace);
```

Json Merge Patch:

```cs
var jsonMergePatch = new V1Scale { Spec = new V1ScaleSpec { Replicas = request.Replicas } };
var patch = new V1Patch(jsonMergePatch, V1Patch.PatchType.MergePatch);
await client.PatchNamespacedDeploymentScaleAsync(patch, request.Deployment, request.Namespace);
```

#### About the different patch options:

They are described here (official C# client):
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/blob/master/src/KubernetesClient/Kubernetes.Header.cs#L32

- Nice article about the difference between JSON Patch and JSON Merge Patch: https://erosb.github.io/post/json-patch-vs-merge-patch/
- Strategic merge patch is a custom k8s version of Json Patch:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-api-machinery/strategic-merge-patch.md
- And ApplyPatch is the "server side apply" that replaces it in yaml format:
  https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/server-side-apply/